# Using internet connection through USB while debuging - Android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, usb, adb

I'm developing application on Android device with Eclipse/ADT. What I need is to use network connection through my PC while debuggin my application. It doesn't work in normal Charging/Sync mode, though you can debug your app in Eclipse. When you change connection type to network through PC I can connect to websites but now you can't debug your app as ADT doesn't see device.

Is there any fix or resolution to this problem ? Unfortunately I don't have possibility to use Wi-Fi :(

Comment: Have you tried debugging on the emulator? Usually the emulator will have Internet connectivity through the PC. When the app is ready on the emulator, you can download it to the phone and test.

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9441879/779408

Answer (score 0):

3.
          * If you're developing on Ubuntu Linux, you need to add a rules file that contains a USB configuration for each type of device you want to use for development. Each device manufacturer uses a different vendor ID. The example rules files below show how to add an entry for a single vendor ID (the HTC vendor ID). In order to support more devices, you will need additional lines of the same format that provide a different value for the SYSFS{idVendor} property. For other IDs, see the table of USB Vendor IDs, below.
               1. Log in as root and create this file: /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.

```
              For Gusty/Hardy, edit the file to read:
              SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"

              For Dapper, edit the file to read:
              SUBSYSTEM=="usb_device", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666"
           2. Now execute:
              chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

You can verify that your device is connected by executing adb devices from your SDK platform-tools/ directory. If connected, you'll see the device name listed as a "device."

If using Eclipse, run or debug as usual. You will be presented with a Device Chooser dialog that lists the available emulator(s) and connected device(s). Select the device upon which you want to install and run the application.

If using the Android Debug Bridge (adb), you can issue commands with the -d flag to target your connected device.
USB Vendor IDs

This table provides a reference to the vendor IDs needed in order to add USB device support on Linux. The USB Vendor ID is the value given to the SYSFS{idVendor} property in the rules file, as described in step 3, above.
Company USB Vendor ID
Acer    0502
Dell    413c
Foxconn     0489
Garmin-Asus     091E
Google  18d1
HTC     0bb4
Huawei  12d1
Kyocera     0482
LG  1004
Motorola    22b8
Nvidia  0955
Pantech     10A9
Samsung     04e8
Sharp   04dd
Sony Ericsson   0fce
ZTE     19D2